# how to remove comments from a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script that is getting a script file as a param. It should remove comments from the file and pipe it to another script. (with no temp file if possible)

at the beginning I was thinkig of doing this

```
cut -d"#" -f1 $1 | ./script_name
```

but it also clears a part of lines which aren't comments, because there are a few commands which uses # in them (counting string chars for example).

is there a way of doing it without a temp file?

Comment: Without examples of cases where `#` is not a comment separator, we can't really improve on what you already have.

Comment: What about quoted #, as in `echo " ## Welcome ##"`

Comment: By "notes", do you mean "comments"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **inline** sed with better regex:

```
sed -i.bak '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d "$1"
```

- `^[[:blank:]]*#` will match `#` only if is preceded by optional spaces at each line
- `-i.bak` option will inline edit the input file with `.bak` as the extension of the backup file in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one very bash-specific way of stripping comments from a script file. It also strips the she-bang line, if there was one (after all, it's a comment), and does some reformatting:

```
tmp_="() {
$(<script_name)
}" bash -c 'declare -f tmp_' | tail -n+2
```

This converts the script into a function, and uses the `bash` built-in `declare` to pretty-print the resulting function (the `tail` removes the function name, but not the surrounding braces; a more complicated post-process could remove them, too, if that were judged necessary).

The pretty-printing is done in a child `bash` process both to avoid polluting the execution environment with the temporary function and because the subprocess will effectively recognize the string value of the variable as a function.

**Update:**

Sadly, post shellshock the above no longer works. However, for patched bashes, the following probably does:

```
env "BASH_FUNC_tmp_%%=() {
$(<script_name)
}" bash -c 'declare -f tmp_' | tail -n+2
```

Also, note that this method does not strip comments which are internal to command or process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general this type of problem can be solved without a temporary file.

This however will also depend on the complexity of the parsing required to determine when the comment delimiter character doesn't in fact introduce a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Using python3 and install [`pygments`](https://pypi.org/project/pygments/)

```py
from pygments.lexers.shell import BashLexer
from pygments.token import Token, is_token_subtype

def delete_comments(fname):
    src = open(fname, "r").read()
    dst = open(fname, "w")
    for token in BashLexer().get_tokens(src):
        
        if not (is_token_subtype(token[0], Token.Comment)):
            dst.write(token[1])
        
        if token[0] == Token.Comment.Hashbang:
            dst.write(token[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    delete_comments("/path/to/your/shellScript.sh")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read the question carefully. The author is trying to do this from within a shell script: "I'm trying to make a script that is getting a script file as a param. It should remove comments from the file and pipe it to another script."

So although this Python script may remove the comments, it doesn't solve the author's problem.

Comment: And I have the same needs to delete the comments . So I share my method to this author.