# Delete all Bash comments

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How can I match and delete all comments from the line? I can delete comments starting from new line, or the ones not in quotes using sed. But my script fails in the following examples

```
This one "# this is not a comment" # but this "is a comment"
```

Can sed handle this case? if yes what is the regex?

Example:

- Input:

  ```
  This one "# this is not a comment" # but this "is a comment"
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  This one "# this is not a comment"
  ```

Comment: post an example along with the expected output.

Comment: A comment is a word (obeying bash's convoluted quoting rules) which starts with an unquoted #. That's very tricky to recognize with a regular expression, because determining the range of a quoted expression can only be done with an understanding of bash syntax. And the syntax is recursive: `cmd "$(other_cmd #comment` is legal (though not complete).

Comment: I know it is tricky. Spend lots of time trying to figure it out... It means there is no simple solution using sed?

Comment: There are no simple solutions using `sed`. Not even complicated ones. Perhaps there are insanely complicated ones, though, but nobody even bothered to think about it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe you could recommend some other tools I can use in bash?

Comment: @user2590816: Can you tell us why you want to strip that comments? Are you parsing a configuration file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove comments from a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291228/how-to-remove-comments-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: @user2590816: The best tool is often bash itself :) See my answer to the question I marked as duplicat.

Comment: Many people in this forum are trying to use `sed`,`grep`,`awk` as an interpreter, compiler, parser of XML, CSV or some other format. They are just not made for this task! They can work in some cases but almost every time you can find a little bit more complex input when the solution will fail.

Comment: @Vytenis Can you suggest some tools that are made for this task?

Comment: javacc/jjtree probably, but it's a steep curve to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that ***#*** is not a comment when it is in quotes or escaped with backslash, then we can define the following regex:

```
(ES|RT|QT)*C?
```

where

ES - escape sequence: \ followed by 1 char

```
\\.
```

RT - non-special regular text

```
[^"\\#]*
```

QT - text in quotes

```
"[^"]*"
```

C - comment starting with unescaped, unquoted hash sign # and ending with the end of line

```
#.*
```

The possible solution using *sed*:

```
sed 's/^\(\(\\.\|[^"\\#]*\|"[^"]*"\)*\)#.*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lexical analyzer like [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex) directly applied to the script. In its manual you can find "[How can I match C-style comments?](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/How-can-I-match-C_002dstyle-comments_003f.html)" and I think that you can adapt that part to your problem.

If you need an in-depth tutorial, you can find it [here](http://home.deib.polimi.it/scandale/?p=/content/teaching/2013/lfc); under "Lexical Analysis" section you can find a pdf that introduce you to the tool and an archive with some practical examples, including "c99-comment-eater", which you can draw inspiration from.

Comment: thanks for information. I ended up writing C-style code which traces each character on the line and stops as soon as it sees '#' outside double quotes. Don't think it is efficient solution, but at least it works