# Remove all comments from a bash script

Tags: bash, parsing, grep, comments

I came across this interesting snippet of code that removes comments from a bash script, and I have some uses for it so I keep it in my `.bashrc`

`alias decomment='egrep -v "^[[:space:]]*((#|;|//).*)?$" '`

However, it only strips lines that *start* with a comment. Is there a way to extend this code so that it can also strip comments at the *end* of lines. e.g. lines like this:

`MyVariable=stuff   # This is my variable`

Comment: This removes lines starting with # inside here documents too. Is that intended?

Comment: remove the `^` ?

Comment: You mean multiline comments @oguz? Yes, I guess it will, that's a tricky one. Removing the `^` is a good idea @markp, except for situations where I have a line `MyHeaderString="#####" #This goes under titles`. And of course "here documents", as @oguz says.

Comment: `grep -v` removes entire lines. If you removed the check for the beginning of a line, it will remove `MyVariable=stuff` because it has a comment after it.

Comment: Also, `#` can be used for other things besides comments, such as an ordinary character in a string. You need language-specific parsing to be able to remove comments in a more general way without breaking that.

Comment: Basically, this alias isn't for removing all comments, it's just for removing comment **lines**, i.e. lines that are only comments. This is usually the most useful for not cluttering up output when you're reading a file.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291228/how-to-remove-comments-from-a-bash-script/25293910#25293910 (Note: the first script in the answer hasn't worked for some time, but the second one still seems to work.)